# Eliminar elemento repetido ingresado por usuario

Tags: c, array

hace poco estoy viendo programación C y comenzamos con los arreglos, hay un ejercicio donde tengo un arreglo de tamaño N con números repetidos (ingresados por el usuario), lo que me pide hacer es que el usuario ingrese un número y verifique en el arreglo si se encuentra, en caso de ser así que elimine la posición del último número repetido(ej: 1 2 3 2 4 >> 1 2 3 4), ahora bien si solamente se repite 1 vez que elimine directamente. Éste último punto me sale, pero a la hora de comparar si hay más repetidos termina haciendo cualquier cosa, a todo esto lo mando a un nuevo arreglo que lo nuestro al final.
Y bueno, esa es duda/problema/situación, si alguien fuera tan amable de ayudarme, se lo agradezco.
Saludos :D

[Editado]

```
int main(){
  int arr[n],nuevo[n],i,j,x,nro,cont,band=0;
  printf("Ingrese numeros, si son repetidos no importa\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Ingrese el numero: ");
    scanf("%i",&arr[i]);
  }
  printf("Ingrese un numero a eliminar: ");
scanf("%i",&nro);
  for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    cont=0;
    if(nro==arr[i]) cont++;
    if(cont==1){
      x=i;
      while(x<n){
        arr[x]=arr[x+1];
        x++;
      }
    }
  }
  for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)   printf ("%i ",arr[i]);
```

Con este código lo que hace es eliminar las veces que con el cont es 1, por lo tanto me va a eliminar el mismo numero siempre, y lo que quiero es que solamente sea la última posición.

Comment: ¿Muestras el código de lo que intentaste? Así se te puede ayudar mejor.

Comment: Por favor, podrías mostrar el código así te ayudamos? saludos

Comment: y si recorres el vector al reves.. y eliminas lo primero que encuentres?? ;)

Comment: Recorri de manera inversa, pero al momento de haber mas de 2 repetidos, se borran esos 2 (Ej: 2 3 2 5 2 >> 2 3 5 0)

Answer (score 2):

El codigo tiene unos cuantos problemas, pero referente a la pregunta:
el problema es que cuando elimina un numero y corre los demas elementos, el contador va a la siguiente iteracion y se salta un numero:

problema:
1 2 2 2 3

output:
1 2 2 3

cuando revisa el segundo dos, lo borra y mueve el array, asi que se queda apuntando al siguiente elemento, y cuando le das i++ en la siguiente iteracion del for te lo saltas

lo que podrias hacer es [edited]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int arr[3], i, x, nro, cont;
  int n = 3;
  printf("Ingrese numeros, si son repetidos no importa\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Ingrese el numero: ");
    scanf("%i",&arr[i]);
  }
  printf("Ingrese el numero para revisar: ");
  scanf("%i", &nro);
  cont = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (nro==arr[i]) {
      if (cont) {
        x = i;
        while(x<n){
          arr[x]=arr[x+1];
          x++;
        }
        i--;
        n--;
      }
      cont = 1;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%i ", arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Agregue el i-- pero no influye, sigue en la misma, o sea: 1 2 3 2 4 >> 1 3 4 0, sigue eliminando todas las igualdades, copie tu códio para corroborarlo otra vez y dio lo mismo.

Comment: el problema era que la variable cont era asignada a 0 en cada iteracion del ciclo por lo que borraba a todos

Comment: si estas ejecutando esta solucion directa no va a funcionar, el problema es que nro no lo asignas nunca

Comment: Sí, ahí me fije que copie mal el código, ya lo cambie, gracias por el dato.

Comment: Puse mi solucion arriba

Comment: Sí la vi, ya pude solucionarlo, muchas gracis Daniel :D

Comment: puedes aceptar mi solucion?

Comment: @Edgardo_22, si mi solucion te ayudo a resolver el problema, considera aceptar mi solucion para cerrar esta pregunta. Si lo hiciste de otro forma tambine puedes mostrarlo para que quede constancia en el sitio.